# Warning with React Bootstrap tooltip: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `show`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip, warnings

I'm getting mad from that. I would like to get rid of that warning:

> index.js:1446 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute
>   `show`.
>
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: show="true"
>   or show={value.toString()}.
>       in div (created by Tooltip)

I'm making a validation form for registrating users. I show tooltip, when password validation fails - when passwords in two inputs are different.

I have attatchRefs in the constructor:
`this.attachRefPass = targetPass => this.setState({ targetPass });`

Next, between other begin values in constructor:

```
this.state = {
 [...] 
      password: "",
      password2: "",
      showTooltipPass: false,
[...]
}
```

Validation method:

```
 passwordValidation = () => {
    this.setState({
      showTooltipPass: this.state.password === this.state.password2
    });
  };
```

And the Form and Tooltip components:

```
<Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridUsername">
                <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  required
                  name="username"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                  ref={this.attachRefUser}
                />
                <Overlay
                  target={targetUser}
                  show={showTooltipUser}
                  placement="right"
                >
                  {props => (
                    <Tooltip id="overlay-example" {...props}>
                      There is one username like that already in the system!
                    </Tooltip>
                  )}
                </Overlay>
              </Form.Group>
```

The Tooltip is from react-boostrap:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/

Comment: It seems like in line `show={showTooltipUser}` your `showTooltipUser` is a boolean value.  Try passing some dummy string instead of `showTooltipUser` (i:e `show={"lorem"}`) and see if the warning comes up or not.

Comment: Unluckily it doesnt work, get the same error as I described @helloitsjoe below. It wants a boolean :<

Answer (score 6):

It is [the bug](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3450) that was fixed that Overlay outputs `show` value as `Boolean`
You may fix the issue localy with overriding `show` prop

```
{props => (
    <Tooltip id="overlay-example" {...props} show={props.show.toString()}>
        There is one username like that already in the system!
    </Tooltip>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a Boolean value (`true` or `false`) in `state.showTooltipPass`, and passing it to Overlay’s `show` prop, which appears to expect a string value (`”true”` or `”false”`).

If you pass the value in as `show={showTooltipPass.toString()}`, this will convert the boolean to a string in the place you need it to be a string.

Comment: I forgot to add, that of course i checked that. After doing that, I have that it needs a boolean value :)
I got two warnings:
`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'show' of type 'string' supplied to 'Overlay', expected 'boolean'.
   in Overlay (created by WaitForContainer)`

and

`Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'in' of type 'string' supplied to 'Transition', expected 'boolean'`